# Is it possible to list all the events happening in a process? Linux operating system

Tags: linux, process

I am trying to launch a independent process(via some script).  How to monitor that process via script.  Is that possible?  For example, my process may have four states such as,

1. Initialing
2. Building
3. Compiling
4. Binary created.

Answer (score 0):

lunch via script ?

if you create process via system call fork(), i guess insert print process's state code.